# ppa-purge by URL

Tags: apt, ppa, 18.10

I installed some PPAs. Now, when I run `apt update` some of them seem to be gone.

```
Err:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu cosmic Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Now, I would like to do the following:

```
sudo ppa-purge http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu
```

But this does not work.
I assume ppa-purge only accepts input in the form of `ppa:somerepo/path`

Is there a way to remove a PPA by its http... URL?

Comment: I don't use `ppa-purge`, but try `sudo ppa purge 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu cosmic main'`

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you mentioned [does not contain](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu/dists/) files for *cosmic* (18.10) distro.

So you can simply remove it from *sources.list* with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/atom
```

and then check that `sudo apt update` is successful.